# Обновить страницу через 1 секунду с помощью jquery

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте. Мне нужно при клике обновить страницу через одну секунду, как это сделать помогите?

```
 $('.link a').click(function(){
        location.reload();
    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('.link a').click(function(){
    setTimeout(function() {window.location.reload();}, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Спасибо! класс!

Answer (score 2):

Читать про интервалы.
[SetInterval](http://javascript.ru/setInterval)

[SetTimeout](http://javascript.ru/setTimeout)